# On page load submit input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
    <script>$(function(){

        $('#url').keypress(function(event) {
            var v_url = $('#url').val();
            if(event.which == 13 && v_url!=""){
                $('#res').html("Loading...");
                doajax(v_url);
            }
        });

        function doajax(url){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getdata.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {url: url},
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                var h3 = $('<h3>').html("Loading"),
                box = $('#res').html("").append(h3);
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    box
                    .append('<ul>')
                    .append("<li>"+data[i].email+"</li>")
                    .append("<li><a href='"+data[i].name+"'>"+data[i].lastname+"</a></li>")
                    .append("<ul>");
                }
            }).fail(function(){
                $('#res').html('Error');
            });
        }

    });

 </script>
```

```
<input type="text" id="url" value="https://www.example.com<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" style="width:600px;height:30px;font-size:25px">
```

How can i submit this input when page loads??

And the only way i can submit this input is by pressing ENTER Key.

i tried to do a button submit but it didn't work.

I am doing this because for example i enter the www.example.com/BillGates and when i enter this page url i use a php code to get the current page url so i put it in the input value, when i open the page i don't want people than to press the enter key in the input form but i want the get the results automatically on page load so they don't need to press the enter key.

Comment: i don't understand why would you want to submit on page load.  anyway you can do a page on load function  `$(window).load(function() {});`

Answer (score 0):

well you can do this.............

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#enter_key_id").click();

 });
```

this click your enter button at page loads................

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit a input but you can submit a form:

In your PHP:

```
<form id="form-id" action="url.php" method="POST">
  /* better hidden than text if you don't want to the user can change it */
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.example.com...<?php print $anything; ?>" />
</form>
```

In your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form-id').submit();
});
```

But i don't understand why you need to do this. It's no better to do a curl call from the first PHP?

Comment: You don't need a form to send using ajax

Comment: Correct but "No Name" asked for a a input submit no for a ajax send. No need a input to send a ajax call, too is unnecesary to send a ajax call in the page load for that reason i ask if is not better to do a curl call.

Comment: that doesn't make sense since they are using ajax in the code in question